# Angular JS issue when implementing another angular lightbox plug in

Tags: angularjs, lightbox

```
angular.module('birdsApp.controllers', ['bootstrapLightbox']);
angular.module('birdsApp.controllers', []).
controller("birdssController", ['$scope','$http', function($scope, $http, Lightbox)
{    

    $scope.nameFilter = null;
    $scope.searchFilter = function (writer) {
        var keyword = new RegExp($scope.nameFilter, 'i');
        return !$scope.nameFilter || keyword.test(birdfinder[1]);
    }; 
    $http.get('app/demo2.txt?callback=JSON_CALLBACK').success (function(data,index){
    $scope.birdfinderlist = data.aaData;
      console.log(index);
      console.log(data.aaData[1].list[1].bird_img);
      //$scope.birdfinderlist2 = data.aaData.list;
      //console.log(data.aaData[1].list.bird_englishname);
      $scope.openLightboxModal = function (index) {
        //Lightbox.openModal($scope.images, index);
        console.log(data.aaData[1].list[1].bird_img);
        Lightbox.openModal(data.aaData[1].list[1].bird_img, index);
      };
    });
  //   $scope.openLightboxModal = function (index) {
  //   Lightbox.openModal(index);

  // }
}
]     
);
```

I wanted to add light box when clicking on the image in the project and  have added following line code in my existing code.

```
 angular.module('birdsApp.controllers', ['bootstrapLightbox']);
```

&

```
$scope.openLightboxModal = function (index) {
        //Lightbox.openModal($scope.images, index);
        console.log(data.aaData[1].list[1].bird_img);
        Lightbox.openModal(data.aaData[1].list[1].bird_img, index);
      };
```

But its throwing following error

```
angular.js:5765 TypeError: Cannot read property 'openModal' of undefined
at Object.$scope.openLightboxModal (http://192.168.0.200:81/rnd/angular/all_birds/js/controllers.js:62:21)
at http://192.168.0.200:81/rnd/angular/all_birds/bower_components/angular/angular.js:6393:19
at http://192.168.0.200:81/rnd/angular/all_birds/bower_components/angular/angular.js:13268:13
at Object.$eval (http://192.168.0.200:81/rnd/angular/all_birds/bower_components/angular/angular.js:8153:28)
at Object.$apply (http://192.168.0.200:81/rnd/angular/all_birds/bower_components/angular/angular.js:8233:23)
at HTMLAnchorElement.<anonymous> (http://192.168.0.200:81/rnd/angular/all_birds/bower_components/angular/angular.js:13267:17)
at http://192.168.0.200:81/rnd/angular/all_birds/bower_components/angular/angular.js:1980:10
at Array.forEach (native)
at forEach (http://192.168.0.200:81/rnd/angular/all_birds/bower_components/angular/angular.js:154:11)
at HTMLAnchorElement.eventHandler (http://192.168.0.200:81/rnd/angular/all_birds/bower_components/angular/angular.js:1979:5)(anonymous function) @ angular.js:5765(anonymous function) @ angular.js:4812$apply @ angular.js:8235(anonymous function) @ angular.js:13267(anonymous function) @ angular.js:1980forEach @ angular.js:154eventHandler @ angular.js:1979
controllers.js:61 https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/27/Podiceps_cristatus_2_-_Lake_Dulverton.jpg/220px-Podiceps_cristatus_2_-_Lake_Dulverton.jpg
```

My existing working example is here

```
http://mraje.in/angular/all_birds/index.html
```

& edited error page is here

```
http://mraje.in/angular/all_birds/index2.html
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with the injection in the controller.

change:

```
controller("birdssController", ['$scope','$http', function($scope, $http, Lightbox)
{
```

to

```
controller("birdssController", ['$scope','$http','Lightbox', function($scope, $http, Lightbox)
{
```

Comment: i have added this but throwing another error here
    http://mraje.in/angular/all_birds/index2.html

Comment: did you include the source in index for the lightbox??. angular.module('birdsApp.controllers', ['bootstrapLightbox']).
controller("birdssController", ['$scope','$http','Lightbox', function($scope, $http, Lightbox)
{

Comment: i have downloaded plug in from here http://compact.github.io/angular-bootstrap-lightbox/demo1/

Comment: when i use newer version of angular library from lightbox plug in, its working... i think newer version of angular library not supporting existing code. which is working on http://mraje.in/angular/all_birds/index.html